# fullCalendar read data for 40 days

Tags: fullcalendar

fullCalendar readdata for 40 days
I want to use fullcalendar, something like this url
http://www.mikesmithdev.com/fullcalendar-jquery-ui-modal/
and for data sourse I use method

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", ''/control/action/?parameters');
```

where $evtUrl - is url with data filter spacified without date period.
debugging action in I see 2 parameters added

```
[start] => 2014-09-28
[end] => 2014-11-09
```

But I expected date period for current week(7 days), but it looks like that form today 10-18 period is -20 and +20 days
If there is a way to set period in seven days and change it by clicking to left/right button ?

Comment: Can you try to elaborate on what your problem is and maybe put up a jsfiddle showing what you are having trouble with? It's hard to understand the question as is

Answer (score 0):

When adding an EventSource the startParam and endParam are sent automatically according to your current view on the calendar. [Docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)